# Reveal an element upon successful form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form on a wordpress site using a contact form plugin and I would like to reveal a div after the form is submitted successfully.  I tried using jquery to reveal the div upon submit with .submit() but in that case it calls the div to show up whenever the submit button is clicked regardless of whether or not the form was submitted successfully.  Can anyone help me with this as to how to validate whether or not the form was submitted successfully before running the reveal function? My jquery and html is below! Thanks!

```
<form class="subscriptions" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<!-- Inputs and stuff -->
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<div class="subscribe"><h2>some text to be displayed here</h2></div>

<script>
    $("form.subscriptions").submit(function(){
        $("div.subscribe").delay(1200).fadeIn(800, function(){
            $("form.subscriptions").slideUp(1200);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by successful submission? Written to the DB? Because then you need to deal with this on the back-end obviously.

Say I work with Node + Angular. So when I have a successful DB write after post, there's always a server response with a 200 (All OK) header that tells Angular, that everything went fine. You need something like this.

If you are not redirecting after the submit and the unhide of the element signifies the good submit, I think you can use the AJAX post in JQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

This one has a .success() callback, which you can use to do your un-hide logic in.